# Buddypress send admin email notification for multiple xprofile fields when user updates

Tags: email, notifications, updates, profile, buddypress

I am trying to create a function that will send notification email to admin when user updates **only specific** profile fields (for example fields with ID 8,9,10). I dont care about the updated value to be send via email. I just would like to be notified that one of the specific fields have been updated.

I did something like this

```
add_action('xprofile_profile_field_data_updated', 'checkField', 10, 2);

function checkField($field_id, $value) {
// Getting current logged in user's info
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// Checking the hidden value and if it has any value
if($field_id == 8 && $value != '')
    // Sending email
    wp_mail( 'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS ', 'Phone no is changed', $current_user->user_login . ' has changed his phone number ');

if($field_id == 9 && $value != '')
    // Sending email
    wp_mail( 'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS ', 'Address is changed', $current_user->user_login . ' has changed his address ');

if($field_id == 10 && $value != '')
    // Sending email
    wp_mail( 'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS ', 'Email is changed', $current_user->user_login . ' has changed his email ');
  }
```

but it is returning me emails even if a update any other profile field . I just would like to get emails **only when one of those profile fields got updated**. I can't understand how the xprofile_profile_field_data_updated works, or if i would need some other hook.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, i got this working. In case anybody is searching something similar, here it is:

```
function buddypress_profile_update( $user_id, $posted_field_ids, $errors,$old_values, $new_values ) { 
$admin_email = "admin@admin.com";

if ($old_values[4]['value'] !== $new_values[4]['value']) {
 $message = sprintf( __( 'There was a change in the profile of the member:     <strong>%1$s</strong>', 'buddypress' ), bp_core_get_user_displayname( $user_id ) ) . "\r\n\r\n"; 
 $message .= sprintf( __( '<p>The field <strong>Phone</strong> was <br /><hr><br /> %s <br /><hr><br />and now it is:<br /><hr><br /> <strong> %s </strong><hr></p>' ), $old_values[4]['value'], $new_values[4]['value'] ). "\r\n\r\n";
  wp_mail( $admin_email, sprintf( __( 'Change in members Profile' ), get_option('blogname') ), $message    );
 }

  if ($old_values[5]['value'] !== $new_values[5]['value']) {
enter code here
 wp_mail(.......
  }

add_action( 'xprofile_updated_profile', 'buddypress_profile_update', 10, 5 );
```

in case you have checkbox as a field you can use `json_encode` for this to fetch your data out.

For example

```
$message .= sprintf( __( '<p>The field <strong>Checkbox</strong> was <br /><hr><br /> %s <br /><hr><br />and now it is:<br /><hr><br /> <strong> %s </strong><hr></p>' ), json_encode($old_values[5]['value']), json_encode($new_values[5]['value']) ). "\r\n\r\n";
```

Dont forget to put the fields ID in every if inside [ID]